# How to make labels on a logistic plot (made with ggplot/ggplotly) show % vs decimals

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, plotly

I'm not sure if this is exactly the best way to display this - but I am trying to make an easy way for my coworkers to interpret this graph. I want to make it as easiest as possible for them to see the probability of being added to a list is based off score.

I have this code.

```
data <- data %>% 
   mutate(Add = case_when(
     Added == "Yes" ~ 1,
     Added == "No" ~ 0,
   ))
 
 ggplotly(
   ggplot(data, aes(Score, Add)) +
     geom_point(alpha = .25, size = 1 , color = 'grey', fill = 'grey',shape = 21) + 
     stat_smooth(method = "glm" , se=FALSE, method.args = list(family=binomial),size = 1.5 ,lty = 1) +  
     labs(x="Score",y="Probability") + theme_minimal()
 )
```

Which gives me this output. Is it possible to make the Score label be rounded and the Add label be in percentage? So for example in the screenshot below I would have:

Score. 8.50
Add: 72%

Thank you

[image]

data below

```
 data <- structure(list(Added = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", 
                            "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                            "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                            "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                            "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                            "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                            "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                            "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
                            "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", 
                            "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", 
                            "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
                            "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", 
                            "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", 
                            "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", 
                            "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
                            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"
), Score = c(10, 13, 13, 10, 10, 11, 10, 12, 13, 12, 12, 12, 
             10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 11, 8, 12, 5, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 
             0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 6, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 4, 5, 5, 0, 0, 6, 0, 
             5, 0, 5, 5, 0, 3, 4, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 6, 6, 4, 5, 
             4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 14, 
             11, 11, 0, 13, 11, 13, 12, 12, 0, 11, 10, 11, 11, 10, 12, 12, 
             11, 10, 8, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 11, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 12, 
             11, 11, 10, 0, 12, 11, 11, 12, 12, 9, 0, 11, 11, 10, 13, 0, 0, 
             11, 12, 14, 11, 11, 11, 14, 14, 10, 11, 16, 12, 11, 10, 14, 13, 
             14, 12, 11, 12, 12, 12, 11, 13, 10, 11, 12, 14, 12, 11, 0, 9, 
             13, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 13, 12, 15, 10, 8, 13, 11, 0, 11, 0, 
             12, 14, 11, 12, 11, 0, 8, 0, 10, 0, 15, 10, 13, 12, 15, 8, 8, 
             10, 14, 10, 10, 10, 11, 15, 15, 14, 11, 13, 15, 12, 11, 14, 11, 
             10, 10, 11, 14, 12, 9, 12, 0, 12, 0, 9, 10, 13, 12, 15, 11, 12, 
             10, 11, 11, 10, 15, 10, 11, 14, 13, 13, 13, 12, 13, 9, 0, 10, 
             0, 0, 13, 12, 10, 10, 11, 12, 10, 13, 11, 13, 13, 12, 13, 12, 
             12, 11, 12, 11, 13, 0, 10, 10, 11, 14, 12, 13, 13, 12, 10, 13, 
             11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 12, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 12, 12, 
             13, 13, 12, 13, 12, 13, 0, 11, 12, 0, 0, 9, 13, 11, 15, 14, 14, 
             13, 11, 11, 14, 10, 13, 9, 9, 12, 11, 16, 14, 14, 14, 10, 8, 
             14, 13, 9, 11, 12, 14, 10, 13, 12, 13, 10, 13, 15, 10, 7, 8, 
             12, 11, 14, 12, 10, 0, 10, 13, 11, 11, 0, 11, 9, 11, 10, 7, 9, 
             12, 9, 10, 9, 7, 11, 11, 11, 16, 10, 13, 13, 19, 7, 12, 6, 9, 
             13, 5, 10, 13, 10, 9, 14, 9, 10, 13, 14, 14, 9, 12, 12, 13, 15, 
             14, 13, 14, 13, 0, 14, 0, 0, 8, 10, 13, 0, 13, 5, 10, 11, 13, 
             13, 13, 12, 11, 9, 13, 7, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 15, 8, 11, 9, 9, 
             14, 15, 13, 9, 13, 13, 13, 12, 13, 0, 10, 10, 9, 9, 8, 10, 9, 
             11, 10, 10, 0, 0, 10, 9, 0, 12, 0, 10, 11, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 
             12, 13, 9, 10, 13, 8, 10, 13, 12, 11, 13, 8, 16, 11, 12, 12, 
             9, 13, 9, 19, 10, 9, 19, 19, 11, 0, 0, 12, 9, 10, 9, 11, 10, 
             8, 9, 9, 13, 13, 11, 11, 10, 11, 10, 11, 12, 8, 12, 10, 9, 13, 
             11, 10, 10, 15, 10, 9, 12, 12, 13, 11, 10, 15, 8, 10, 8, 10, 
             12, 9, 11, 10, 9, 9, 10, 10, 12, 10, 10, 11, 8, 11, 9, 11, 11, 
             10, 10, 8, 10, 10, 11, 0, 5, 8, 14, 10, 10, 10, 11, 12, 11, 10, 
             11, 9, 12, 10, 11, 10, 11, 9, 11, 9, 10, 10, 13, 12, 10, 12, 
             10, 0, 10, 18, 9, 10, 9, 14, 12, 12, 13, 13, 10, 12, 10, 10, 
             15, 11, 14, 8, 10, 16, 10, 12, 11, 7, 7, 13, 10, 13, 9, 11, 10, 
             10, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10, 13, 12, 12, 14, 12, 13, 9, 11, 9, 0, 12, 
             0, 0, 11, 11, 12, 12, 11, 11, 10, 9, 15, 21, 11, 12, 11, 9, 12, 
             0, 10, 14, 14, 13, 13, 7, 13, 10, 10, 10, 12, 0, 13, 12, 10, 
             11, 8, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 11, 0, 13, 7, 10, 10, 11, 13, 11, 
             10, 9, 12, 0, 11, 0, 11, 10, 13, 11, 11, 12, 8, 12, 15, 10)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                         -707L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach to try. First, store your `ggplotly` object. You can access the `Score` and `Add` data, round to the number of desired decimal places, and include whatever formatting you like, and store as a character vector. This can be used to set the `style` as below.

This will adjust the label text for the `stat_smooth` curve points. If you want to adjust the labels differently for the other grey points, you can access the data from `g$x$data[[1]]` and add argument for `traces` when setting the `style` (e.g., `style(text = custom_text, traces = 1`).

```
library(plotly)

g <- ggplotly(
  ggplot(data, aes(Score, Add)) +
    geom_point(alpha = .25, size = 1 , color = 'grey', fill = 'grey',shape = 21) + 
    stat_smooth(method = "glm" , se=FALSE, method.args = list(family=binomial),size = 1.5 ,lty = 1) +  
    labs(x="Score",y="Probability") + theme_minimal()
) 

custom_text <- sprintf("Score:%s\nAdd:%s%%", 
                       format(round(g$x$data[[2]]$x, 2), nsmall = 2), 
                       format(round(g$x$data[[2]]$y * 100, digits = 0)))

g |>
  style(text = custom_text)
```

**Plot**

[image: plotly with custom hover label tooltip]

Comment: Thank you so much this is awesome, I didn't know I could go into that level of customization with the plotly elements. Is there a user guide or documentation that you could recommend?

Comment: Glad this was helpful. I'm not aware of a specific guide, but found a lot of helpful information through related questions on SO and by inspecting the ggplotly object.